# Why I can't disable triggers on a table that has been partitioned?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, database-partitioning

Postgres version: PostgreSQL 15.2 on aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102), 64-bit

Table `users` has a referential constraint to table`activities`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  activity_name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT,
  username VARCHAR(50),
  activity_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (activity_id) REFERENCES activities(id)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (id);

CREATE TABLE users_0 PARTITION OF users
  FOR VALUES FROM (0) TO (100);

CREATE TABLE users_1 PARTITION OF users
  FOR VALUES FROM (100) TO (200);

CREATE TABLE users_2 PARTITION OF users
  FOR VALUES FROM (200) TO (300);

CREATE TABLE users_3 PARTITION OF users
  FOR VALUES FROM (300) TO (MAXVALUE);
```

Below are the results of `\dS+` commands on the table `users` and its partitions.

```
                                              Partitioned table "public.users"
   Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 username    | character varying(50) |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 activity_id | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
Partition key: RANGE (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "users_activity_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (activity_id) REFERENCES activities(id)
Partitions: users_0 FOR VALUES FROM (0) TO (100),
            users_1 FOR VALUES FROM (100) TO (200),
            users_2 FOR VALUES FROM (200) TO (300),
            users_3 FOR VALUES FROM (300) TO (MAXVALUE)
```

```
                        Table "public.users_0"
   Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | integer               |           |          |
 username    | character varying(50) |           |          |
 activity_id | integer               |           |          |
Partition of: users FOR VALUES FROM (0) TO (100)
Foreign-key constraints:
    TABLE "users" CONSTRAINT "users_activity_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (activity_id) REFERENCES activities(id)
```

When I try to disable triggers on the table `users` using this command:

```sql
alter table users disable trigger all;
```

I'm met with this error:

> `ERROR:  trigger "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_572918" for table "users_0" does not exist`

I guess the command to disable all triggers will propagate to all the partitions as this command to disable triggers on only this table would work:

```sql
alter table only users disable trigger all; -- ALTER TABLE
```

I tried to list all triggers for the original table and partitions and they return different trigger names. PostgreSQL **seems** to use the triggers' name from the original table and propagates it to the partitions, but with naming differences like this, it would never work right.

Below is the result when I list the triggers on the original table `users` and its partitions.

```sql
-- original table
test=# SELECT
    tgname AS trigger_name
FROM
    pg_trigger
WHERE
    tgrelid = 'users'::regclass
ORDER BY
    trigger_name;
         trigger_name;
```

> ```
> RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_572918
> RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_572919
> ```

```sql
-- partition
test=# SELECT
    tgname AS trigger_name
FROM
    pg_trigger
WHERE
    tgrelid = 'users_0'::regclass
ORDER BY
    trigger_name;
         trigger_name
```

> ```
> RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_572924
> RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_572925
> ```

I'm surprised PostgreSQL is trying to disable a non-existent trigger on the partition. Is this a bug?

Comment: I'd call this a PostgreSQL bug and encourage you to report it. The statement should either work, or it should give a more meaningful error message like "is not supported on partitioned tables".

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  It runs without errors for me.  What version are you running? `select version()`

Comment: I'm using **PostgreSQL 15.2 on aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102), 64-bit**. I was able to confirm that on 14.4 and 14.7, this error doesn't occur. My observation is that on 14.x versions, Postgres doesn't create triggers on the original table but only on the partitions. However, in 15.5, it creates the triggers on both the original table and the partitions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks, I will file a report to postgres.

Comment: I have reported a bug to PostgreSQL team and they said that a fix will be released in 15.3 version in May!

Comment: Great. I hadn't noticed that this bug has already been fixed with [commit 6949b921d5](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=6949b921d545809a83f8a6bad4948f9012a76fb6); it will be fixed in the minor release 15.3. Other versions are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are temporarily disabling triggers, there is a setting for the current session rather than calling the command you have.

```
SET session_replication_role = replica;
```

This will set it back.

```
SET session_replication_role = DEFAULT;
```

http://koo.fi/blog/2013/01/08/disable-postgresql-triggers-temporarily/

---

For disabling triggers for all sessions... use your command.

You probably have special characters (quotes) for that trigger on the one partition.  I'm not sure why.  In order to call a command for triggers, you need to use the same special characters.  You might need to call the disable for each partition.  If you cannot see the name of the trigger on the partition, do one at a time and keep calling your command to get errors on subsequent partitions.  I'm not entirely sure this will solve your issue.  If not, hopefully someone will answer that knows.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

```
alter table "users_0" disable trigger "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_572918";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I have added the **Edit 2** section to clarify my question.

Comment: What is the reason you are disabling triggers on this table?  Also, have any of the commands in my answer worked?

Comment: Ah context is I'm using Rails. It is running the command under the hood: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c567850476dc443563b9be93a129eb09601e25af/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/referential_integrity.rb#L10-L13.

Because I'm unable to modify Rails' behavior, I just want to confirm whether this is the intended behavior of Postgres so that I can relay it back to the Rails team so that they will change the SQL command.

Comment: Rather than changing the source code in your repo, someone should test the entire process in Postgres from start to finish (create table, create trigger, disable trigger, update table, enable trigger), to confirm what caused this issue.  Someone posted a comment saying the create table statement isn't valid.  That might be the actual issue here.  Fixing code without testing will cause problems!!!  Avoid it, even if you really know what you're doing.  This avoids time, this avoids remediation, this avoids blame, this avoids a lot!  But most importantly, it gives you reliable code!

Comment: It would also be interesting to see the code which created the triggers.  I don't see that in the question.  It might be helpful for reproducing to see how two triggers are on the table and two are on partitions.

Comment: Hey I should clarify that I didn't create the triggers. It is the system triggers that Postgres created for referential integrity constraints. And I have updated the code in the question (my bad for posting the wrong code snippet). You can actually use it to create a minimal reproducible example in your local.

Comment: Good to know.  If you can reproduce on the same version of Postgres, and are able to successfully disable all triggers individually, then you may need to write a query to find them and disable them in the code with a loop since the system names them its own way.

Answer (score 0):

For others using <v14.8 this can also occur as described in [this issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/17886-5406d5d828aa4aa3@postgresql.org). It was fixed on v14.8 as you can see in the [v14.8 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.8/)